# can't create Django Sync DB in Visual Studio 15 Enterprise

Tags: django, python-3.x, visual-studio-2015

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtdMZ.png)
Visual Studio error:
Unknown command: 'syncdb'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
The Python REPL process has exited

### Advice with migrate doesn't work.

Python 3.5, Django 1.9.2, VS 15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `syncdb` in Django 1.9.2. Instead of `syncdb` use `migrate`.

> Prior to version 1.7, Django only supported adding new models to the database; it was not possible to alter or remove existing models via the `syncdb` command (the predecessor to `migrate`).

### Update:

For the newbies it is better to rely on manual commands, without any IDEs.
For that being said there is NO WAY you can avoid [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/) to understand what is going on.

Comment: I can't understand, how I must use migrate, I can't find where I must write "migrate" ?
I wrote "manage.py migrate" in IDLE, that doesn't work

Comment: where I must run  "python manage.py migrate" ? cmd, IDLE, python ?

Comment: @StaxaKovalenko you need to run `cmd` and go to your project's folder (with `cd`), is should consist of `manage.py` file, apps and settings folder. If you have `virtualenv` you should firstly activate it and then run `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: @vishes_shell migrate is not sufficient. This comes along with makemigrations. Your answer let believe that `syncdb` was renamed `migrate` and is roughly the same. Yet it is completely different and I think it requires a little more reading to understand how migrations work.

Comment: @AntoinePinsard i'm absolutely agree, mate! However the problem is probably with VS 2015 that it still use as a command `syncdb`, rather that `migrate`.

Comment: Oh Ok, I see, sorry. That's the problem with IDEs, you don't see what you are doing. :P

Answer (score 0):

`syncdb` was deprecated in django 1.7, introducing migrations, and removed in django 1.9. [Check out this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/) to learn about migrations.